# clkI/O 256 & 1024 (From prescaler) not working with driving PWM on Nano board

Tags: arduino-uno, led, arduino-nano, pwm, rgb-led

I've been working with PWM in TIMER0 of my nano board.

So, it's working now and I know how to set OCR0A or OCR0B.

Then, I went to play with Clock Select Bits CS02 CS01 CS00 in TCCR0B.

0, 8 and 64 prescaler configurations worked as I also don't see the effect on the LED fade speed.

But the more problem I get is that 256 and 1024 prescaler don't work at all and the LED goes on all the time.

What is the problem?

The code:

```
void setup() {
    DDRD |= (1<<DDD6);
    TCCR0A |= 0xC1;
    TCCR0B |= 0x00; // this works for 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 only
    }

    void loop() {
    uint8_t i;
    for (i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
      OCR0A = i;
      _delay_ms(1);
    } 
    }
```

regards,

Comment: Do you have the real code? And if you are using Arduino framework, don't forget Timer0 is used for counting millis(), so you might just messed up some delay time

Comment: Code added :) it's working with the delay as you mentioned that timer0 is used for counting millis, but I'm working with true C coding. Is it still used for _delay_ms and _delay_us? Thank you,

Comment: You *have* been waiting 4 or 16 times as long to try to see any change, right?

Comment: No, `_delay_*()` are implemented with assembly code loops (which means that `F_CPU` must be set correctly).

Comment: I was waiting 4 or 16 times for what exactly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is the prescaler on `Timer0` is already configured to divide clock source by `64` `CS01` and `CS00` are set `(0b00000011)`.

And you are using bitwise OR to "change" prescaler: `TCCR0B |= 0x05;` or `TCCR0B |= 0x04;`. But this'll result into the clock source `7` `(0b00000111)` - clock source is expected on `T0` input counting on rising edge.

Comment: WOW :) you absolutely right. The bitwise OR was the problem. OK so when to use the bitwise OR when I'm testing different codes and when not to use it? I use it with DDRs PORTs which works well, so here it did a problem !! Thank you very much for the help 3>